How to Move Face to be Coplanar with Another
How can I move the bottom face so that it is coplanar with the top face?
I tried doing "Selection to Cursor (Keep Offset)". That's almost right, but I only want the bottom face moving along the Y axis.
I could just move the bottom face along the Y axis and eyeball it, but there must be some way to make it exact.


Activate the snap to vertices option, move the face along Y and make it snap on a vertex of the top face?

@moonboots I was about to say the same but you got there first! :^)

@John Eason I'm not sure this is what he wants though   ;)

Enable Snap To Vertex:

Move the face along Y and snap to a vertex of the top face:


Oh my gosh yes, this works perfectly well. I was trying to snap to the cursor but obviously your solution works. Thank you!
